# How can I apply borders to a specific cell with laravel excel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I've been working with Laravel Excel for a few weeks now and I like it alot.
But I can't apply borders to a specific cell.

This is my code:

```
$sheet->cell('A1', function($cell){
    $cell->setBorder('solid','solid','solid','solid');
});
```

Some background info about the cell 'A1':

- It isn't a merged cell.
- It does contain plain text only.

The sheet variable is a valid Excelsheet and I can add data to this.

Did I make a mistake somewhere or is this a known bug for Laravel Excel?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me

```
$sheet->cell('A1', function($cell){
    $cell->setBorder('thin','thin','thin','thin');
});
```

Please refer to this [documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/reference-guide#borders), there is no `solid` option. Yes, maybe there are some typos in that `laravel-excel` example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sheet->setBorder('A1', 'solid');
```